# triggering of events manually in slickgrid

Tags: javascript, jquery, slickgrid

I have implemented an onclick event in slickgrid. It works fine if I click on the grid using the mouse but if I trigger a click event from the web console, the value of the row in args is displaying as negative. So I'm not able to proceed further. Any help is appreciated.

```
grid.onClick.subscribe(function(e, args) {
    var row = args.row;
```

The `row` is coming as negative if I trigger a click event on the grid using javascript from web console.

Comment: Why is triggering a click via the console important if the code is working under normal circumstances?

Comment: I have robot test case that is not working.

Comment: I found the solution for the issue. We can trigger the slickgrid events in following ways:- grid.onClick.notify({row:0})

Answer (score 2):

I found the solution for the issue. We can trigger the slickgrid events in following ways:- grid.onClick.notify({row:0})